# Kafka / ZooKeeper ACL Auditing

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, acl

I am looking for a way to keep an audit log of ACL changes in our Kafka / ZooKeeper setup. I am using the Confluent bundle.

I already increased all `LOG_LEVEL` in the `log4j.properties` to `DEBUG`, but I can't find any entry whenever the ACL has changes.

Does someone had the same issue - or even a solution to that matter?
Thank a lot, Thomas

Answer (score 0):

See the debugging part here: https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authorization.html
Summarizing

1. On Confluent Platform 0.9.0.0 or above change ```

```
log4j.logger.kafka.authorizer.logger=WARN, authorizerAppender
```

to

```
log4j.logger.kafka.authorizer.logger=DEBUG, authorizerAppender
```

in the default log4 properties.

2. On earlier versions or when using custom properties add to the log4j.properties:

```
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/kafka-authorizer.log
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.logger.kafka.authorizer.logger=DEBUG, authorizerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.authorizer.logger=false
```

Does that help?

Comment: thanks for your answer. I already did that. By setting debug level to `DEBUG` I can see addiontally all successful ACL authorizations. Thats good so far.
But what I do not see in any log is the change of ZooKeeper ACL. Any idea, if this can be logged? E.g if I change the ACL via Kafka ACL CLI.